# How to send string to EditText in Fragment after scanning in MainActivity

Tags: android

What would be the best way to get a scanned string to my EditText in my `Fragment`
I tried to use `bundles`but because I want to receive the string in an existing `Fragment`someone said it would be better to search for another way. Atm Ive got my `onClickListener` in my `Fragment`whicht calls my `scanSerial`method in my `MainActivity`. In my `MainActivity`there is also the `onActivityResult`

```
inputSerial = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_serial);
        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_scan_serial);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).scanSerial();
            }
        });
```

onActivityResult & scanSerial from my `MainActivity`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String scanContent = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String scanFormat = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

            switch (requestCode){
                case (10):{
                    String[] Split = scanContent.split("\\s");
                    String product = Split[0];
                    String label = Split[1];
                    String serial = Split[2];


                    mydb.insertData(product, label, serial, mac, daaid, bill);

                    Fragment fragment;
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragment = new ListViewFragment();
                    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    break;
                }
                case (11):{

                    scannedResult = scanContent;

                    break;
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            Log.d("TEST", "result_canceled");
        }

}

public void scanSerial(){
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 11);
}
```

I know that I should receive the string AFTER scanning the serial but I dont know how to do it. Can I listen if the `onActivityResult` method sets the scannedResult string from my Fragment?

Comment: you can `startActivityForResult` in your fragment itself and do `onActivityResult` in your fragment itself

Comment: I forgot to explain this. I need `onActivityResult` in my `MainActivity` because there is another Scan method. One of the both methods has to send their results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just call your scan method and define "your_intent_code.

```
public void scan() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A");
    startActivityForResult(intent, "your_intent_code);
}
```

dependend on the intent code you can define the action in your `onActivityResult`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String scanContent = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

                switch (requestCode){
                    case (your_intent_code):{
                        // DO SOMESTHING
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to scan a barcode and you're using the zxing application, it is better to use zxing's IntentIntegrator.

in your scanSerial there would be

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
integrator.initiateScan();
```

Then in your onActivityResult in MainActivity you create your new Fragment and pass the result to it

```
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
ft.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

or to all fragments if you need that

```
for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Then you do your manipulations with EditText in Fragment code

```
IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (scanResult != null) {
        String scannedString = scanResult.getContents();
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to scan an insert my serial. Not perfect but for the moment it works:

```
    inputSerial = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_serial);
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_scan_serial);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).scanSerial();
        }
    });

    if ((((MainActivity) getActivity()).scannedResult) != null );{
        inputSerial.setText(((MainActivity) getActivity()).scannedResult);
    }
```